# Storyboard created items are not initialized

Tags: ios, storyboard

I just migrate an older project in 6.0 using xib files to storyboard.  All the old pages work fine.  Then I am trying to add new interface items on one of the views, like a label, an activityindicator, etc.  The problem is all the new interface items I added are not initilized.

I connect the newly created interfaces to IBoutlets on a view controller, and check in the debugger, they are nil.  As a comparison, if I open a new project and create those elements in the interface, they will be ininitialized.

The older project has to ben in 6.0, becuase one of the libary it uses are not compatible with 7.0 and up.  If I build the project in 7.0, there will be certain symbol not found errors.

Anyone has a clue here?  thanks.

Comment: Are you seeing the old interface items on those controllers where you don't see the new ones? Do you have the xib files in the project or have you deleted those? IT would be helpful if you could give more detail on how you did the migration.

Comment: how you are pushing/presenting views?

Comment: 1. Yes.  I can see old items.  I have deleted the old xib file.  I created the storyboard file and copied the stuff on old xib file onto the storyboard and reconnect the copied items to the outlets on controllers.

Comment: 2.  I use storyboard created connections to present views.